# Double recursion in MIPS - wrong output

Tags: recursion, assembly, mips, cpu-architecture

I am trying to implement a program wherein the user's input(n) is given and the program will follow this algorithm:

```
if n = 0,   f(n) = 2
else if n is odd, f(n) = 3*f(n-1) + 1 
else if n is even, f(n) = f(n-2) + 2*f(n-1)
```

Here is my attempt at it so far:

```
.data 0x1001000C
        .word 4
prompt2:    .asciiz     "Result: "
answer:     .word       0

.text
    lui $t0,0x1001
    lw  $a0,0xC($t0)     #n
    sw  $v1,0x4($t0)
    addi $t8, $t8, 1
    jal function
    add  $v1,$s1,$v1
    sw   $v1,answer

    # Print out the result
    li      $v0,4
    la      $a0,prompt2
    syscall

    lw      $a0,answer
    li      $v0,1
    syscall

    li      $v0,10
    syscall

function: 
    beq  $a0, $0, f_exit        #if n=0
    andi $t9, $a0, 1        
    beq  $t9, $t8, f_odd        #if odd

    addi $sp,$sp,-8     # push stack
    sw   $ra,4($sp)     # store return address
    sw   $a0,0($sp)     # save n

    addi $a0, $a0, -1   #n-1
    jal function
    mul  $v1, $v1, 2    #2f(n-1)  

    lw  $v1,0x4($t0)
    lw  $a0,0($sp)          # reload 1st operand

    addi $a0, $a0, -2       #n-2
    jal function

    lw      $ra,4($sp)      # restore return address
    lw      $a0,0($sp)      # restore n
    addi    $sp,$sp,8
    j exit

f_odd:
    addi $sp,$sp,-8     # push stack
    sw   $ra,4($sp)     # store return address
    sw   $a0,0($sp)     # save n

    addi $a0, $a0, -1   #n-1
    jal function
    mul $v1,$v1,3       #3f(n-1)  
    addi $s1, $v1, 1    #3f(n-1)+1

    lw  $v1,0x4($t0)
    lw  $a0,0($sp)          # reload 1st operand

    lw      $ra,4($sp)      # restore return address
    lw      $a0,0($sp)      # restore n
    addi    $sp,$sp,8
    j exit

f_exit:
    addi $v1,$v1,2

exit:
    jr $ra
```

However, I could never get the right input. For example, an input of 4 should give me an output of 98 but instead this program gives me 9. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you try single-stepping with your debugger to see if it branches the way you expect?  I'm guessing not, because `addi $t8, $t8, 1` doesn't set `$t8` to 1.  Maybe you meant `addi $t8, $zero, 1` to get a `1`?  But it would be easier to `bne $t9, $zero, f_odd`: compare against zero is easier than compare against 1.  Or change it to `beq $t9, $zero, f_even` and fall-through to the odd case if that's just as easy.  IDK how many other bugs there might be, but I noticed that weird use of `$t8` as an extra input to the function, depending on random garbage in `$t8` at the start.

Comment: Yes. $t8 is set to 1 and I've tried both of your suggestions when it comes to the odd-even thing and nothing still changes. That lessens the things that I need to debug though. Thanks @PeterCordes!

Comment: It's still a bad idea to depend on registers being initially zero, unless that saves you anything and you make a comment to note that fact.   In this case you could just write it without reading it first.  Or better, avoid needing `$t8` at all.

Comment: Anyway, when you were using the debugger to find out that `$t1` was actually `1`, did you find out where it was not branching the way you expect, or not saving/restoring something?

Comment: Yes. It was actually the $s1 and $v1 registers which were being overwritten every branch. I don't know how to fix this issue though.

Comment: Use temporary registers that you can clobber while you're calculating your return value.  The `even` branch might need to do extra saving/restoring across the first call, but the odd branch is nearly tail recursion, and doesn't need the original `n` after the call returns, just constants.  (`(retval << 1) + retval + 1`).  Don't use `mul` by 2, use a shift.

Comment: Will try this. Thanks again!